# I'm unable to run inotify in php

Tags: php, inotify

I installed Inotify for php using the command **pecl install inotify** and I added this statement 
**extension=inotify.so** in php.ini file. When I run a php file with $fd = inotify_init(); ,it  is showing server error "The website encountered an error while retrieving" and if I remove the inotify_init() statement is fine. Can  any tell me where is wrong.

Comment: have you set `display_errors` to `on` in `php.ini`? or add these 2 lines before calling `inotifiy_init();`, `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @anurupr after adding the two statements it is showing **Fatal error: Call to undefined function inotify_init()**

Comment: then the extension hasn't been enabled. can you verify if there is no `;` before `extension=inotify.so` in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If the installation was ok, restarting the server should probably solve it.
On Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: After doing this also no use